# C++ Can someone explain what these for loops are saying?

Tags: c++, for-loop, conditional-operator

So this code is the base outline for a boggle game from online that I copied over. 
SOURCE: http://www.codingfriends.com/index.php/2010/06/10/boggle/

```
bool findUsersWord(string findThis, Grid<char> &theBoard, Vector<cell> &theRoute, string alreadyFound, int placeY, int placeX)
{  
  // need to find the findThis  base case
  if (findThis == alreadyFound)
    return true;
  // need to find the first letter within the board and then progress around that.
  if (alreadyFound.empty())
  {
    for (int rows = 0; rows < theBoard.numRows(); rows++)
      for (int cols = 0; cols < theBoard.numCols(); cols++)
        // find the each character within the 
        if (theBoard[rows][cols] == findThis[0])
        {
          alreadyFound = findThis[0];
          cell newR;
          newR.row = rows;
          newR.col = cols;
          theRoute.add(newR);
          if (findUsersWord(findThis, theBoard, theRoute, alreadyFound, rows, cols))
            return true;
          else
            // clear out the found Board 
            theRoute.clear();
        }
  }
  else
  {
    // try and find the next letters within the area around the base letter
    // spin around the letter 3 * 3 grid
    for (int y= (placeY > 0 ? placeY-1: placeY); y <=(placeY == (theBoard.numRows()-1) ? placeY : placeY+1);y++)
      for (int x=(placeX > 0 ? placeX-1: placeX); x<=(placeX == (theBoard.numCols()-1) ? placeX : placeX+1); x++)
        if ((theBoard[y][x] == findThis[alreadyFound.length()]) && (!(y==placeY && x ==placeX)))
          // already used letter
          if (!placeAlreadyUsed(y,x,theRoute))
          {
            alreadyFound += findThis[alreadyFound.length()];
            cell newR;
            newR.row = y;
            newR.col = x;
            theRoute.add(newR);
            if (findUsersWord(findThis, theBoard,theRoute, alreadyFound, y, x))
              return true;
            else
            {
              if (alreadyFound.length() > 1)
                alreadyFound = alreadyFound.substr(0, alreadyFound.length()-1);
              theRoute.removeAt(theRoute.size()-1);
            }
          }
    return false;
  }
  return false;
}
```

The code below is the code in question which is part of the code above.

```
for (int y= (placeY > 0 ? placeY-1: placeY); y <=(placeY == (theBoard.numRows()-1) ? placeY : placeY+1);y++)
  for (int x=(placeX > 0 ? placeX-1: placeX); x<=(placeX == (theBoard.numCols()-1) ? placeX : placeX+1)
```

I am wondering if someone could turn this code into more simple code that doesn't involve the using of ? and that. I do know the simple parts of it such as the "?" means return and ":" means next line, but I am lost in the fact that it is being used in a for loop and the fact that it would just look like

```
if(placeY > 0)
 return playceY-1
placeY;
```

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure you quite understand the `?` and `:` operators...Basically what `placeY > 0 ? placeY-1 : placeY)` is saying is this: "is placeY greater than 0? If so, then the result of this expression is `playeY-1`, otherwise it's `placeY`"

Comment: @pretic: "operator", not "operators". `? :` is a single operator with three operand expressions.

Comment: @HenningMakholm - whoops, yes you're right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `? :` block is just a strange looking if statement. It's an *inline* if, if you will.

Here's the format

```
argument ? result evaluated to if true : result evaluated to if false
```

Here's an example

```
1<2 ? "Hurray" : "boo"
```

Will evaluate to `"Hurray"` because 1<2 is true. However, if we switch it to `1>2` it will evaluate to `"boo"`.

Comment: The `? :` block is not a statement at all.

Comment: Considering what the OP's confusion is, this is probably not the best description. `?:` does _not_ "return" in the sense of "stop executing the current function and continue executing the caller where it left off", like the `return` statement does. What `?:` does is, like all other expressions, to _evaluate_ to this or that, not to _return_ something.

Comment: So Could i put an if statement in a for loop then?

Comment: @KurtE Yes. Your code already has an if statement inside a for loop. You just can't put an if in the `()` of a for loop. As in, `for(not here;nor here;not here) { but anywhere in here }`

Answer (score 2):

> I do know the simple parts of it such as the "?" means return and ":" means next line

Um, no. That's not what it means at all. `?:` is one operator with three operand expressions, one of which appears between the `?` and the `:`.

```
placeY > 0 ? placeY-1 : placeY
```

is an expression that means: "If `placeY > 0` then evaluate `placeY-1`; otherwise evaluate `placeY`".

The idea of the code is that we want, for some reason, to iterate over all positions of the board that are next to (placeX,placeY). Those positions form a rectangle, and the `?:` operators are used to compute the left, right, top and bottom limits of that rectangle. For example the expression quoted above is for the top coordinate. It is usually `placeY-1`, except that if `placeY` is already 0, there is no row on the board above it, and in that case `placeY` itself is the top row.

Comment: So Could i put an if statement in a for loop then?

Comment: @Kurt: You can put an if statement in the _body_ of a for loop, but in between the parentheses of the `for(   ;   ;  )` header only _expressions_ are allowed.

Comment: The important thing to take out of this is that there is no change in the flow of execution of your program.  That whole `placeY > 0 ? placeY-1: placeY` will evaluate to a single value, which can then be assigned to `y`.  For instance, since `if` statements look like `if(expression){...}`, you could legally put that line inside the `if` condition.  The expression is completely different than an if statement, even though we use the word 'if' when we describe the behavior of the `?:` operator.